# How to link to another part of another page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the below as my nav, however, the index.html.erb#meetflappy is throwing up an error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/preorder/index.html.erb"
```

I'd like it so that when users click meetflappy tab, they are brought to the index page and specifically to the #meetflappy part. Now this works when I'm on the index page and it just links to #meetflappy but when I'm on another page i'm having trouble here. Please advise:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper-nav">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <%= link_to logo, root_path, class: 'brand' %></a>
    </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class=""><%= link_to 'Meet Flappy', 'index.html.erb#meetflappy' %></li>
         <li class=""><%= link_to 'Details', 'index.html.erb#details' %></li>
         <li class=""><%= link_to 'FAQ', faq_path %></li>
         <li class=""><%= link_to 'Flappy\'s Story', flappystory_path %></li>
         <li class=""><%= link_to 'About Us', about_path %></li>
         <li class=""><%= link_to 'Checkout', preorder_checkout_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

`<%= link_to 'Meet Flappy', 'index.html.erb#meetflappy' %>`

to this:

`<%= link_to 'Meet Flappy', root_path(anchor: 'meetflappy') %>`